# Convergence or Divergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\arccos\left(\frac{k^3}{2k^3+1}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> How can I find the sequence $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\arccos\bigg(\frac{k^3}{2k^3+1}\bigg)$$ is converge or Diverge

What I try

$$\arccos x+\arcsin x=\frac{\pi}{2}\;\forall x\in[-1,1]$$

And $\sin x<x\Longrightarrow x<\arcsin(x)\Longrightarrow -x>-\arcsin x$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{k^3}{2*k^3+1}\bigg)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\arcsin\bigg(\frac{k^3}{2k^3+1}\bigg)<\underbrace{\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\bigg)}_{\text{Diverge}}$$

I did not understand How do I find whether original series is converge or Diverge . Help me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It clearly diverges, since $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\arccos {k^3\over 2k^3+1}=\arccos {1\over 2}={\pi\over 3}$$